# Fitting a quadratic curve for each data set that has different lengths

Tags: r, lm, predict

I would like to fit a quadratic to (Time,SkinTemp) for each *id* in the following data.frame df. Each id has a different number of Time,SkinTemp entries so I'm stuck with 'predict'

```
df<-data.frame(Time=seq(65),
               SkinTemp=rnorm(65,37,0.5),
               id=rep(1:10,c(5,4,10,6,7,8,9,8,4,4)))
```

So far I have:

```
#Fit the model y=x^2+x+C
fitted_models = df %>% group_by(id) %>% do(model = lm(SkinTemp ~ Time+I(Time^2), data = .))
```

So far so good. Here's where I'm stuck. How do I pass the original Time data into the predict function below?

```
#Predict data points for each quadratic 
predQ<-sapply(unique(df$id), function(x) predict(fitted_models$model[[x]]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fitted`:

```
lapply(fitted_models$model, fitted)
```

Comment: Super, thanks. I think I made my question a bit short. The subsequent idea is to find the maximum curvature of the quadratics that I create by feeding into features(x,y) for each id. For this I unsuccessfully wrote: c<-sapply(unique(predQ$id), function(x) features(predQ$Time[predQ["id"]==x],predQ$SkinTemp[predQ["id"]==x],smoother="smooth.spline"))

Comment: Do you mind adding that to the question? It's tough to see how to modify this answer to get what you're looking for in the comment.

Comment: No, do not change the question in material ways after it has already been answered.